# Creating a custom calendar/ month view in iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, grid-layout, custom-view

I'm trying to create a custom calendar/ month view from scratch similar to this:

[image]

And with that I'm wondering what the correct approach would be. I'm calculating which weekday the first day of the month falls on (mon-sun), and the number of days in the month. This should be enough to determine how the calendar should look, but I'm stuck trying to figure out a way to lay this all out.

Is it best to have 37 buttons in a grid layout in the storyboard and iterate through them somehow, changing their label, or dynamically create these buttons on the fly? Is there any element/ framework in iOS I could make use of to make this process easier?

If going for the latter, how would you set up the constraints to make this scalable on different size classes and screen sizes?

Comment: You can use a UICollectionView. It comes with nice methods to put re-occuring code for each day-button.

Comment: @Tim a `UICollectionView` is probably most definitely the way to go! I briefly thought about it myself, but got a little stuck in thinking about a fixed grid using auto layout. Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction. Sadly you didn't post this as a question, so I can't accept it as the answer. However I'll give you an upvote 

Comment: No problem. The one difficulty I had was that I had to set layout to vertical to get the numbers to layout across rows then down. But this causes collectionView swipe to go vertical as well. So I created my own gesture listeners to swipe sideways. Good luck!

Comment: did you ever create your custom calendar control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim in first comment is right. The best way to build layout for custom calendar view such yours is UICollectionView.
 Also to make less mistakes you can use NSDate extensions like this one: https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions

Comment: Like Tim in the comments said, a `UICollectionView` is definitely the way to go. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!